# xib reference IBOutlet / IBAction not refactored correctly by XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refactoring

Ok, this is a pretty weird error. I have a `UIViewController` subclass and an associated Xib

It's part of an inherited project built originally by an outsourcer and a lot of properties and methods have badly spelled names, `categorys` instead of `categories`, `merchantes` instead of `merchants`, `don` instead of `done` and so on...

Mostly refactoring these has been straightforward, and XCode's symbol rename refactoring tool has handled them ok.

However with the xib and controller in question, after refactoring, there are some runtime errors, namely `this class is not key value coding-compliant` and `unrecognised selector` errors, which both name the old `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` names.

When grepping for the names, they don't appear, and searching specifically in the xib as XML source, they also don't show up.

I've worked around this by adding in the two offending symbols, while maintaining the references and all other calls to the corrected names. (ie. the old names don't link to any other code or xib references.)

The question is, why and where are these old symbol names being called?

(note: all IB references have been checked, and the project has been cleaned several times.)

Here's the references in question (correctly mapped in IB.)

[image: ib property reference]

[image: ib selector reference]

And the *connections* showing in the source view...

Note the old references "navTitleLavel" and "donAction" are the throwing the errors if they're removed from the source, although they do not show as *connected* in the margin.

[image]

[image]

## Now fixed

### (without doing anything, assume a cache held the symbols)

See my answer below, it appears that the symbol references were being cached *somewhere*, and without additional action the errors are no longer being thrown (when removing the old name references.)

Note, this was resistant to cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite numerous cleans and triple checking that `grep`, `ack`, `ag` and XCode's project wide text search **could not** find the references throwing the error.  The error persisted.

However, this morning I tried again, and lo and behold the ghost references no longer throw the errors.

It appears that there is some sort of nib reference caching which persists after Project Clean, but expires after x time.

Note: the clean operation was run in excess of 10 times, without fixing the error.

I've also updated the question to provide some illustrative detail.

Comment: Maybe you deleted the app from phone or simulator, or reset your simulator. Xcode tries to avoid copying resources when it can. You could say the installed app is the cache.

Comment: @JonReid Do you mean when it magically started working again? It was rebuilt in the exact same way as it was the day before, ie. a project clean was run, and a build to the phone. Nothing different, other than the amount of time elapsed between attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into such weird errors before and solved it by

1. Clean the project (Command + K).
2. Check every connection in IB so that they do not link to old stuff (don, categorys etc)
3. Restart xCode. (Really quit the application and restart it)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Looks like there are some references lurking in the XIB xml after all. I'll add a check-mark on this for suggesting a double check.  I'm mystified why the grep didn't pick them up before I posted this.

Comment: Removing them and Cleaning (I'd done this before.) didn't solve the problem, but thank you for suggesting I double check.

Comment: Just rebuilt the project this morning, and the ghost references are gone.

Comment: Possibly that is what fixed mine problem too. I updated my answer to account for that possibility too. Great that you got your project running again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well, and a simple clean isn't always enough to get rid of the remaining references which may be in cached files on your device.  Make sure to actually delete the app off the iOS device or reset the simulator if a simple clean doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's possible that the NIB's were cached on the device, but without supporting evidence that this (selectively) takes place, and why it would expire after approximately 12 hours, the question is still not properly answered. If it happened all the time, and routinely expired after a number of hours, it would be a little more credible.